# Adding a Table to an Word Document via Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm currently trying to compare numbers between two Excel documents and write the results of the tests to a table in a Word document. I've been able to establish a connection to the document, but I can't get the actual addition of a table to work.

This is what I have:

```
Dim wordObj As Object
Dim outFile As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wordObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If wordObj Is Nothing Then
    Set wordObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

Set outFile = wordObj.Documents.Add

wordObj.Visible = True
wordObj.Tables.Add Range:=wordObj.Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3

wordObj.Selection.Tables(1).Select

With wordObj.Selection
        .TypeText ("test1")
        .MoveRight (wordObj.wdCell)
        .TypeText ("test2")
        .MoveRight (wordObj.wdCell)
        .TypeText ("test3")
        .MoveLeft (wordObj.wdCell)
        .MoveLeft (wordObj.wdCell)
        .MoveDown Unit:=wordObj.wdLine, Count:=1        
End With
```

I had also tried just splitting the page into 3 columns, which worked, but i couldn't get the program to actually switch between columns when I wanted (I tried using InsertBreak(wdColumnBreak)). So for some reason, adding columns works, but tables don't

Comment: Your code looks like you started out and gave up. It will be hard to find someone who will pick up where you left off. Why not include the code you say you tried in your question. Then, instead of writing code for you someone can correct your errors. One error I notice is that you can't make the `wordObj` visible. What you probably intend to do is to activate the window in which the `wordObj` has opened the `outFile`, except that your code doesn't open it. Since you use the `wordObj` from the Excel application late binding might be a problem. Better declare `Dim outFile As Word.Document`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only other code I had was just trying to select the table and write some values to it, which I figured was irrelevant since the table didn't exist in the first place, but I edited my post. And in that time I got the code to work by changing some incorrect references (i.e. trying to access a property of wordObj instead of outFile). I also changed the outFile's declaration to Word.Document as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the Tables.Add is that you're calling it on the wrong object, plus it's the method of the word document so that expects a "word range" whatever that is. Here's a working piece of code, but it's copying and pasting the table over:

```
Sub aaa()
    Dim wordObj As New Word.Application
    Dim outFile As Word.Document
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    wordObj.Visible = True
    Set outFile = wordObj.Documents.Add
    outFile.Activate

    Debug.Print "Here!"

    Set s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Call s.Range("E4:J10").Copy
    ' Call outFile.Tables.Add(wordObj.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0), NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=3)
    Call wordObj.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks precision. You should try to build it more methodical, like, first create an instance of the Word application. Then let that application create a document. Then place a table into that document. Then look for a cell in that table. And add text to that cell only now.

In comparison, you create the Word application, don't create any document, add a table to the document which doesn't exist, and - presumably in desperation - then try to add text to the application. The Word application doesn't have a selection (your `wordObj.Selection`), only a document does.

The following code does what you want. I have written it for your ease of understanding. Don't think it's "baby language" because it isn't. It just doesn't cut corners. You can learn how to cut corners after you are more proficient - if you still want to. Bear in mind, the more corners you cut the less stable your code will be.

```
Sub WriteToWordTable()

    ' declarations for the Excel application:
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    ' declarations for the Word application:
    Dim wordObj As Word.Application
    Dim outFile As Word.Document
    Dim outTable As Word.Table
    Dim wdRng As Word.Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Ws.Cells(2, "A").value = "Test1"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If wordObj Is Nothing Then
        Set wordObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    Set outFile = wordObj.Documents.Add
    With outFile
        Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
        Set outTable = .Tables.Add(Range:=wdRng, _
                                   NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3)
    End With

    With outTable
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = Ws.Cells(2, "A").value
        .Rows.Add
        .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Test2"
    End With

    With wordObj.ActiveWindow
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With

'    outFile.Close
'    wordObj.Quit
End Sub
```

BTW, you don't need to make the Word document visible at any time. You could quietly close the Word application and continue working in Excel. However, for that purpose you would need to save the `outFile` before closing it and then shutting down Word.